# Seg fault after failing to loop multiple times in C

Tags: c, for-loop, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation, operator-precedence

I am doing an exercise where I create an array and populate the elements with integers. I first input the length of the array to malloc for the size. Then, I scan the elements of each point in the array in a for loop.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int scaning(int ** array){
    int size;
    scanf("%d", &size);
    *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    //printf("%d\n", size);
    for (int i=0; i<=size; i++){
        int num;
        scanf("%d", &num);
        *array[i] = num;
    }

    return size;
}


int main(){
    
    int * array;
    int zero;
    zero = scaning(&array);
    //printf("%d\n", zero);
    printf("LOOPS\n");
    for (int i=0; i<= zero; i++){
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After I input the elements to populate the array twice I get a seg fault. I usually put in size for the array of 5, get to input 2 numbers and then it crashes. Not sure where I went wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to check that the input succeeds etc. `if(scanf("%d", &size) != 1 || size < 1)  { /* failure */ }`

Comment: When you use `i<=size` as your loop termination condition, that is an off-by-one error that will overflow your buffer which only has enough storage to hold `size` elements.  Use `i<size` instead.  And yes, definitely check your input succeeded -- `scanf` must return 1 in this case on successful input, and if it doesn't then you must not use `size` as you cannot guarantee it holds any sensible value.  Same thing goes with `malloc` -- NULL-test the result before you start using the memory.

Answer (score 5):

The for loops in your program like this

```
for (int i=0; i<=size; i++){
```

have the invalid condition `i <= size`. The valid range of indices is `[0, size)`.

You need to use the condition `i < size`.

Another problem is related to the operator precedence.

Instead of

```
*array[i] = num;
```

that is equivalent to

```
*( array[i] ) = num;
```

you need to write

```
( *array )[i] = num;
```

or at least

```
array[0][i] = num;
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
size_t scaning( int **array )
{
    *array = NULL;

    size_t size = 0;
    scanf( "%zu", &size );

    if ( size != 0 ) *array = malloc( sizeof( int ) * size );

    if ( *array != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        {
            int num = 0;
            scanf( "%d", &num );
            ( *array )[i] = num;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        size = 0;
    }

    return size;
}
```

Correspondingly the variable `zero` (why is it named "zero"?) also must have the type `size_t`.

Pay attention to that you should free the allocated array in main like

```
free( array );
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `size` is the number of integers in your array, you don't want to loop until `i<=size`. You want to loop until `i < size` only. Remember that the first item in your array has index zero, so the index of the last item is size minus one. If you loop until and including size as index, that will cause a seg fault.